# What does command "echo run -d" do?

Tags: shell-script, echo

I was going through some scripts in my organisation, and I'm wondering what 
`echo run -d` does.

Note: The script was used to execute a jar file with some arguments.

Answer (score 2):

`echo run -d` outputs the string `run -d` on standard output.

Here, it may be that `echo` has been used to output some debugging information or for reminding someone to run `run -d`, or it may pass that string to something else that reads the standard output of that particular script, for whatever reason. Since the question does not mention any context for the line of code, I can't really speculate more around what the intention of the code might be.

Comment: Actually it is being used to run some kind of utility . I saw it in 1 of the production our servers hence can't paste the code , will check with 1 of the earlier developers & update here. Thanks for the response though